# How to make a PUT JQuery Ajax request to JsonBlob

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a PUT request on JsonBlob but i get this error

"XML interpretation error: no root element found Address: https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/43c83fba-f591-11e8-85a9-1542923be246 Row number 1, column 1:"

Here is the function:

```
backup : function(data){
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    var url =  "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/43c83fba-f591-11e8-85a9-1542923be246";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "PUT",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        error:function(xhr, status, e){
            console.log(status)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API's error message indicates that it is trying to parse your request as XML.

The [documentation for the API](https://jsonblob.com/api/) shows a Content-Type header on the request:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> {"people":["fred","mark","andrew"]}
> ```

You haven't included that.

Add it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json"
```